# Taxonomy on each field value

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, media

What is the best way to **add taxonomy terms to each field value** (uploaded with plupload or multiupload at once) of a imagefield (should look like http://www.binaerschmiede.at/test/imagefield-tags.jpg)?

Of course I want to access this terms in views afterwards for creating media overviews.

Is there already a extension/module I've missed so far while searching because I suppose I'm not the first one with that kind of request, am I?

Example:

1. I create a content where I upload 3 pictures to a multiple plupload image field. Entering title, alt text and the tag the first 2 images with "Nature, Animals", the 3rd on with "Nature, Landscape".
2. I create another content with 2 images tagged as with "Zoo, Animals".
3. In a View I want all to get all images tagged with "Animals", on another view all images tagged with "Nature", ... and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a multi-value [Field Group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group), with one taxonomy term reference (tag), and one image. Field group values can be used in views via [Field group views](http://drupal.org/project/field_group_views) module.

Alternatively you can do the same using [Field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module - younger, without 6.x roots, written to utilize entity api (and it means native views integration).

For bulk uploading, there is [Field Collection Bulkupload](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_bulkupload), it seems to work, if with issues (as to be expected for alpha module). If you need bulk upload capabilities and equivalent of collections, joining efforts with it's team should be your best bet.

Comment: Added link to a module aimed at bulk uploading into collections. Just be sure to take a look at open issues. If you'll fix `.info` file as described and don't make tags required it should work for you all right.

Comment: I think I'll forget about it atm and wait for a fixed version of Field Collection Bulkupload.

Comment: No point in waiting, it's left as is with patches in issue queue. If you want it, you will have to take over I guess. But it's easier than writing new fields with references and views integration from scratch.